# UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1 encoding: replace special characters with closest equivalent

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1

Does anyone know of Python libraries that allows you to convert a UTF-8 string to ISO-8859-1 encoding in a smart way?

By smart, I mean replacing characters like "–" by "-" or so. And for the many characters for which an equivalent really cannot be thought of, replace with "?" (like `encode('iso-8859-1', errors='replace')` does).

Comment: There's [Unidecode](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode) for ASCII but I'm not aware of an equivalent for ISO-8859-1.

Comment: @MarkRansom Yes, unidecode could be an option, but not ideal, since it would not keep common accentuated characters found in European languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the first 256 code points of Unicode match ISO-8859-1, it is possible to attempt encoding to ISO-8859-1, which will take care of all characters 0 to 255 without errors. For the characters leading to encoding errors, unidecode can be used.

The following works on Python 2 and 3:

```
from builtins import str
import unidecode

def unidecode_fallback(e):
    part = e.object[e.start:e.end]
    replacement = str(unidecode.unidecode(part) or '?')
    return (replacement, e.start + len(part))

codecs.register_error('unidecode_fallback', unidecode_fallback)

s = u'abcdé–fghijkl'.encode('iso-8859-1', errors='unidecode_fallback')
print(s.decode('iso-8859-1'))
```

Result:

```
abcdé-fgh?ijkl
```

This however converts non-ISO-8859-1 characters into an ASCII equivalent, while sometimes it may be better to have a non-ASCII, ISO-8859-1 equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

Well I am not aware of any existing library, but [Unidecode](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode) has a GPL 2 license meaning that it can be used as a base for another program. Its main function has a special case processing for all ASCII code point (below 128) keeping them untouched. If you just extend that processing to Latin1 letters (code points below 256) you will get a special version that keeps Latin1 chars and uses unidecode for all other characters.

As I know no character beyond 255 that should be mapped to a latin1 non ascii character, that should do the trick.

Comment: Please explain your last sentence... all characters beyond 128 are non-ASCII and some of then are Latin-1

Comment: No need to fork Unidecode, you can accomplish the same thing with a generator: `''.join(c if c <= '\xff' else unidecode(c) for c in string)`. Admittedly it will be slower than a simple call to `unidecode`.

Comment: @MarkRansom: After a look to Unidecode source, I just wanted to avoid a call to unidecode per character for performance reasons. But you are right for a not too frequent use, that would be enough.

Answer (score 1):

libiconv has a "TRANSLIT" feature which does what you want

Answer (score 0):

Works with TKinter and export to Excel:

```
def utf_2_iso(text: str) -> str:

    try:
        result: str = text.encode('ISO-8859-1', errors='ignore').decode('utf-8', errors='ignore')

    except UnicodeError:

        result = text

    return result
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).